# error: URL can not open stream

Tags: java, android, url

When I use `openStream()` to parse XML from a web service, I get the error:

> Can not open stream

I've checked the URL and it's still working.

```
URL url = new URL("http://uitbookshop.php0h.com/PHPService/findbyname.php?name=thu");
Log.d("search", "getXML::url "+url.toString());
InputStream iS;
try {
    iS = url.openStream();

    doc=db.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(iS, Charset.forName("utf-8"))));
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("search", "Can not open stream");
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: suggestion remove log in the IOException catch block, and use the `e.printStackTrace()` to get the detail error information.

Answer (score 6):

Have you given appropriate Permissions?
make sure you have following permission added to the manifest

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```